# How to combine types that are being imported from relative path?

Tags: typescript

I have a project written in TypeScript with custom typings which I'm importing to my `.ts` modules with import statement:

`import { MyCoolInterface } from './types'`

When I'm building my project with tsc, I'm getting a declaration file `index.d.ts` along with `index.js` and my typings are not getting concatenated with tsc-generated ones. tsc just copies string `import { MyCoolInterface } from './types'` into the generated declaration file and obviously it's could not be found in my **dist** directory so typings appears to be broken. Is there a way to concatenate auto-generated types with my own into a single file?

My `index.d.ts`:

```
export interface UmbressOptions {
    isProxyTrusted?: boolean
    rateLimiter?: {
        enabled?: boolean
        requests?: number
        per?: number
        banFor?: number
    }
    clearQueueAfterBan?: boolean
    logs?: boolean
    whitelist?: Array<string>
    blacklist?: Array<string>
    checkSuspiciousAddresses?: {
        enabled?: boolean
        token?: string
        action?: 'block' | 'check'
        banFor?: number
        cookieTtl?: 1
    }
    advancedClientChallenging?: {
        enabled: boolean
        cookieTtl?: number
        content?: string
        userAgentsWhitelist?: RegExp
        cache?: 'redis'
        cacheHost?: string
        cachePort?: number
    }
}
```

Getting merged with tsc-generated `index.d.ts`:

```
/// <reference types="ioredis" />
/// <reference types="express" />
/// <reference types="pug" />
declare module 'abuseipdb' {
    import { UmbressOptions } from './types' // <------------ Import or export declaration in an ambient module declaration cannot reference module through relative module name.ts(2439)
    import { Redis } from 'ioredis'
    export function checkAddress(ip: string, options: UmbressOptions, redis: Redis, jailKey: string): Promise<void>
}
```

Comment: Good question @JamesJGoodwin! Could you give us an example? How are you using these types in practice?

Comment: @PedroMutter hello. You can visit [JamesJGoodwin/umbress](https://github.com/JamesJGoodwin/umbress) for code examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `typings.d.ts` file to `typings.ts`. Typescript ignores `.d.ts` files when creating the build. For Typescript, all `.d.ts` are just types declarations, useless to javascript. I hope it helps you!

Comment: Thank you very much! Renaming `index.d.ts` to `index.ts` solved my issue.